# disadvantages of using Windows Workflow Foundation wiht ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, workflow

we are planning to use Microsoft Workflow with ASP.net, can any one tel me what are the points to be considered and what will be the disadvantages on using Windows Workflow foundation in developing an asp.net website

Comment: I don't know, why are you planning to use it in the first place? Because it exists?